# starmac simulated_quadrotor a real simulator?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

from where does starmac simulated_quadrotor  get its sensordata for simulation ???
are the sensors(acc,gyro,...) modelled in starmac simulator???
Is starmac a real simulation of a quadrokopter???? It is confusing because the simulated_quadrotor  uses RVIZ.But Rviz is only a Vizualisation,as far as i understand.

I want a real Simulation of my selfmade quadrotor.How can i achieve this?

thanks,greets
adrian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12408/starmac-simulated_quadrotor-a-real-simulator???/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2011-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just noticed this question while browsing around.. I guess this is related to a posting on the starmac-ros-pkg-users list. Dimitri is correct in his assessment--in my [response on the mailing list](http://lists.eecs.berkeley.edu/sympa/arc/starmac-ros-pkg-users/2012-01/msg00001.html) I went into a bit more detail. The tl;dr version is that simulated_quadrotor simulates just enough to give me enough confidence to try something out on the real quadrotor. So if there's a sign error somewhere in the code that will probably be revealed in the simulator but I wouldn't expect it to reveal anything substantially more subtle than that.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2012-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quadrotors are incredibly difficult to simulate. [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gazeboquadrotor/) is the closest I've seen to a "real" simulated quadrotor. The major problem is that this is for Gazebo, but is not integrated into ROS yet. This could be done, but it would require patching Gazebo itself and writing a ROS wrapper for the controller code.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [hector_quadrotor_gazebo package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor_gazebo) seems like what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1